# .NET Core WebApi return Unathorized code to user from middleware

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I want to send user bad request code back when something goes wrong in middleware.

My `Startup.cs` looks like this:

```
// configure method 
                                                                                                         
if (env.IsDevelopment())                                                                                 
{                                                                                                        
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();                                                                     
}                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                                   
app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");                                                                               
app.UseMiddleware<RequestMiddleware>();                                                                  
app.UseMiddleware<SecondRequestMiddleware>();                                                                                                                                                    
app.UseRouting();                                                                                        
                                                                                                         
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>                                                                            
{                                                                                                        
    endpoints.MapControllers();                                                                                                                                           
});
```

My middleware looks like this:

```
public class RequestMiddleware                                                                                                                     
{                                                                                                                                                  
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                   
    public RequestMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)                                                                                                 
    {                                                                                                                                              
        _next = next;                                                                                                                              
    }                                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                                   
    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, IAuthInfoService authInfoService, IPowiadomieniaCacheService cacheService)                  
    {                                                                                                                                              
        string jwt = context.Request.Headers["custom_header"];                                                                                
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(jwt))                                                                                                             
        {
            // no jwt in headers so i want to return Unauthorized to user:
            await ReturnErrorResponse(HttpContext context);                      
        }                                                                                                                                          
    }                                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                                   
    private Task ReturnErrorResponse(HttpContext context)                                                                                          
    {                                                                                                                                              
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";                                                                                         
        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                   
        return Task.CompletedTask;                                                                                                                 
    }                                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
}
```

But still i getting into my `SecondRequestMiddleware`. I want to return `401 Stauts Code` to user, when there is no `jwt` in headers (thats what my `RequestMiddleware` checks) and stopped processing this request.

How to validate request in middleware and if conditions passed, return error code / response to user?

Comment: I just simply break my middleware to smaller parts before your answer but yes, your answer is good as well :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could modify your middleware to short circuit a request, like this.
Where `await context.Response.StartAsync();` will start a response and will not proceed further.

```
public class RequestMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    public RequestMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, IAuthInfoService authInfoService, IPowiadomieniaCacheService cacheService)
    {
        string jwt = context.Request.Headers["custom_header"];
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(jwt))
        {
            // no jwt in headers so i want to return Unauthorized to user:
            await ReturnErrorResponse(HttpContext context);
        }
        else
        {
            await _next(context);
        }
    }

    private async Task ReturnErrorResponse(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
        await context.Response.StartAsync();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> when there is no jwt in headers (thats what my RequestMiddleware
> checks) and stopped processing this request.

You can **terminate the request** by writing the following：

```
await context.Response.WriteAsync("error message");
```

If the headers have the jwt , then you need to **trigger the following middleware** through the following statement, otherwise it will not be executed automatically:

```
 await _next.Invoke(context);
```

More details, refer to [ASP.NET Core Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#create-a-middleware-pipeline-with-iapplicationbuilder).

Change your RequestMiddleware as follow:

```
 public class RequestMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public RequestMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
        {
            string jwt = context.Request.Headers["custom_header"];
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(jwt))
            { 
                await ReturnErrorResponse(context);
            }
            else
            {
                await _next.Invoke(context);// call next middleware
            }
        }

        private async Task ReturnErrorResponse(HttpContext context)
        {
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized; 
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("error message!"); 
        }

    }
```